# How do I run a unified display from multiple computers?

Tags: linux, display, xorg, xdmx

I have two computers, my main computer and a second computer that I have set up elsewhere in my vicinity. The main computer has a dual display, and the second computer has a monitor set up to it. Basically what I'd like to do is set them up so that all three monitors are part of one display.

I am using Linux on both computers. I believe the answer lies somewhere in using Xdmx, but nothing I have tried has worked so far. I've followed through both [this](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/dmx-start.html) and [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-mltihed/index.html) and neither one has proved satisfactory.

Comment: why don't just use VNC or ssh?

Comment: Would that be able to extend my display across the third monitor?